# excel-Vba for loop with If condition taking long time

Tags: vba, excel

I am very much a novice with VBA but i have managed to write code that runs. My issue is that when i run it with many thousands of rows it basically grinds to a halt and nothing happens for well over an hour (when i run for 150K rows). On top of my code i have added:

I have also attempted to avoid using .select whenever i could. Is there anything that i'm missing or is there a way that i could improve my code? Since i've pasted various code i'm sure i've done something wrong.

```
Sub Eng11()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wkb1 As Workbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim wkb2 As Workbook
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim x As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    sPath = "C:\Users\nascd\Downloads\Pronto Master\"
    sFile = sPath & Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("J2").Text

    Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
    Set sht1 = wkb1.Sheets("Data Table")
    Set sht2 = wkb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set ws = sht2

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "AX").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "AZ").Text) = (Cells(i, "AB").Text) And _
            (Cells(i, "BA").Text) = (Cells(i, "AC").Text) And _
            (Cells(i, "AY").Text) = "C" And (Cells(i, "AA").Text) = "E" Then

            Cells(i, "AX").Value = Cells(i, "Z").Value
            Cells(i, "AY").Value = Cells(i, "AA").Value
            Cells(i, "AZ").Value = Cells(i, "AB").Value
            Cells(i, "BA").Value = Cells(i, "AC").Value
        End If
    Next i

    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "AZ").Text) = (Cells(i, "AB").Text) And _
            (Cells(i, "BA").Text) = (Cells(i, "AC").Text) And _
            (Cells(i, "AY").Text) = "C" And (Cells(i, "AA").Text) = "T" Then

            Cells(i, "AX").Value = Cells(i, "Z").Value
            Cells(i, "AY").Value = Cells(i, "AA").Value
            Cells(i, "AZ").Value = Cells(i, "AB").Value
            Cells(i, "BA").Value = Cells(i, "AC").Value
        End If
    Next i

    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "AY").Text) = "1" And (Cells(i, "AA").Text) = "E" Then

            Cells(i, "AX").Value = Cells(i, "Z").Value
            Cells(i, "AY").Value = Cells(i, "AA").Value
            Cells(i, "AZ").Value = Cells(i, "AB").Value
            Cells(i, "BA").Value = Cells(i, "AC").Value
        End If
    Next i

    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "AY").Text) = "2" And (Cells(i, "AA").Text) = "E" Then

            Cells(i, "AX").Value = Cells(i, "Z").Value
            Cells(i, "AY").Value = Cells(i, "AA").Value
            Cells(i, "AZ").Value = Cells(i, "AB").Value
            Cells(i, "BA").Value = Cells(i, "AC").Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't include End Sub

Comment: Why are you using 4 loops? Can you rebuild it with 1 loop only? The time should be divided by 4 then. (Just guessing).

Comment: Take a look at things like `.Offset` or `.Resize` property. Looping 4 times over the same or similar range makes no sense here

Comment: It feels very unintuitive to use `i` for each of those loops

Comment: Indeed, it could be just one loop, On which sheet runs this code? (in this case active one). You could read all into array and change it there and write back to sheet in one time.

Comment: How many Excel files are currently opened when you are running the code? Once a colleague of mine had 20 opened Excels, the code that runs for 3 minutes ran 4 hours, but he was happy, went out for a pizza :) In the new Excel 2016, the instances are a bit different than in Excel 2013, thus it may happen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this code is working and is better suited to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You only need to loop once, your algorithms are the key, if 1st condition is not met, it will go to the next condition, no need to re loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is as condensed as I can make it. Certainly some logic magician could come in and make this shorter but I think they might not be able to fit the `if` logic onto a single line!

This will only loop once, which should have been your biggest obstacle in terms of time to run. I made sure to specify that you're searching in `sht2`, removed some unused variables, and made sure to reset your `application` settings at the end of the sub. Other than that, the only thing I really did was combine your `if` statements as best as I could and put them into one loop.

```
Sub Eng11()

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With


    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Table")

    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = "C:\Users\nascd\Downloads\Pronto Master\"

    Dim sFile As String
    sFile = sPath & sht1.Range("J2").Value2

    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht2 = Workbooks.Open(sFile).Sheets(1)


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sht2.Cells(Rows.count, "AX").End(xlUp).row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow

        With sht2

            If .Cells(i, "AZ").Value2 = .Cells(i, "AB").Value2 And _
               .Cells(i, "BA").Value2 = .Cells(i, "AC").Value2 Then

                If .Cells(i, "AY").Value2 = "C" And _
                   (.Cells(i, "AA").Value2 = "E" Or .Cells(i, "AA").Value2 = "T") Then

                    .Cells(i, "AX").Value2 = .Cells(i, "Z").Value2
                    .Cells(i, "AY").Value2 = .Cells(i, "AA").Value2
                    .Cells(i, "AZ").Value2 = .Cells(i, "AB").Value2
                    .Cells(i, "BA").Value2 = .Cells(i, "AC").Value2

                End If

            ElseIf .Cells(i, "AA").Value2 = "E" And _
                   (.Cells(i, "AY").Value2 = 2 Or .Cells(i, "AY").Value2 = 1) Then

                .Cells(i, "AX").Value2 = .Cells(i, "Z").Value2
                .Cells(i, "AY").Value2 = .Cells(i, "AA").Value2
                .Cells(i, "AZ").Value2 = .Cells(i, "AB").Value2
                .Cells(i, "BA").Value2 = .Cells(i, "AC").Value2

            End If

        End With

    Next i


    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Eng11()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Last As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wkb1 As Workbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim wkb2 As Workbook
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim x As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    sPath = "C:\Users\nascd\Downloads\Pronto Master\"
    sFile = sPath & Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("J2").Text

    Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
    Set sht1 = wkb1.Sheets("Data Table")
    Set sht2 = wkb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set ws = sht2

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "AX").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "AZ").Text) = (Cells(i, "AB").Text) And _
            (Cells(i, "BA").Text) = (Cells(i, "AC").Text) And _
            (Cells(i, "AY").Text) = "C" And (Cells(i, "AA").Text) = "E" Then

            Cells(i, "AX").Value = Cells(i, "Z").Value
            Cells(i, "AY").Value = Cells(i, "AA").Value
            Cells(i, "AZ").Value = Cells(i, "AB").Value
            Cells(i, "BA").Value = Cells(i, "AC").Value
        End If


        If (Cells(i, "AZ").Text) = (Cells(i, "AB").Text) And _
            (Cells(i, "BA").Text) = (Cells(i, "AC").Text) And _
            (Cells(i, "AY").Text) = "C" And (Cells(i, "AA").Text) = "T" Then

            Cells(i, "AX").Value = Cells(i, "Z").Value
            Cells(i, "AY").Value = Cells(i, "AA").Value
            Cells(i, "AZ").Value = Cells(i, "AB").Value
            Cells(i, "BA").Value = Cells(i, "AC").Value
        End If

       If (Cells(i, "AY").Text) = "1" And (Cells(i, "AA").Text) = "E" Then

            Cells(i, "AX").Value = Cells(i, "Z").Value
            Cells(i, "AY").Value = Cells(i, "AA").Value
            Cells(i, "AZ").Value = Cells(i, "AB").Value
            Cells(i, "BA").Value = Cells(i, "AC").Value
        End If

        If (Cells(i, "AY").Text) = "2" And (Cells(i, "AA").Text) = "E" Then

            Cells(i, "AX").Value = Cells(i, "Z").Value
            Cells(i, "AY").Value = Cells(i, "AA").Value
            Cells(i, "AZ").Value = Cells(i, "AB").Value
            Cells(i, "BA").Value = Cells(i, "AC").Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Can you pardon to let me the know the difference of last two Ifs as the function is same for both ifs condition.

Comment: Nice, though I am not sure why OP is starting from the bottom, as no cells are getting deleted

Comment: Why 4 `If` tests when the same code executes if any of them pass? These should at very least be `Else If` so it doesn't test conditions again if prior tests are met.